# How many questions did Neo ask in The Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

In the movie *The Matrix*, Neo seems to ask an *awful lot of questions* to other characters.

**Exactly how many questions did he ask?**

Comment: Were you hoping somebody besides you had gone through the whole movie and counted? Because we all thought you were gonna do that and then tell us.

Comment: Yeap, I might do that. He asks too many questions in the movie, its weird.

Comment: Purely out of curiosity... why?

Comment: A veritable buttload. I've read somewhere that over a third of his dialogue is questions to other cast.

Comment: Now that I see the answer, this question is oddly interesting.

Comment: @amaranth - It was sufficiently interesting that I went through and counted.

Comment: @Valorum I kind of feel like watching the movie and checking the questions off the list now.

Comment: @amaranth - I included [a link to the transcript](http://thematrixtruth.remoteviewinglight.com/html/transcript-of-the-matrix-1.html) for precisely that reason.

Comment: @Valorum I could independently verify the transcript, if I watch it myself.

Comment: @amaranth - Never let it be said that I tried to convince someone *not* to watch The Matrix again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Neo asks **93 distinct questions**, 94 if you include "*What is the Matrix?*" which is posed as a statement rather than a question.

Interestingly, given that Neo  has only 164 lines of dialogue, him asking questions represents more than half (*56%*) of all of his lines in the film.

> **What? What the hell?
>
>   Follow the white rabbit?
>
>   Who is it?
>
>   Got the money?
>
>   You ever have that feeling where you're not sure if you're awake or still dreaming?
>
>   How do you know that name? 
>   Who are you?
>
>   *The* Trinity? That cracked the IRS d-base?
>
>   That was you on my computer. How did you do that?
>
>   Of what?
>
>   Who is?
>
>   What is the Matrix [This one's a bit tricky because he doesn't actually pose it as a question]
>
>   Who's coming for me?
>
>   What the hell do they want from me?
>
>   How?
>
>   But what if they...?
>
>   How do you know all this?
>
>   Why is this happening to me? What did I do?
>
>   How about I give you the finger and you give me my phone call?
>
>   What are you talking about? What, what is happening to me?
>
>   What the hell is this?
>
>   From what?
>
>   What?
>
>   Why?
>
>   What is that thing?
>
>   The Matrix?
>
>   What "Truth"?
>
>   You did all this?
>
>   Did you...?
>
>   Am I dead?
>
>   What are you doing?
>
>   Why do my eyes hurt?
>
>   Morpheus, what's happened to me? What is this place?
>
>   When?
>
>   Right now we're inside a computer program?
>
>   This, this isn't real?
>
>   AI? You mean Artificial Intelligence?
>
>   I can't go back, can I?
>
>   For what?
>
>   Zion?
>
>   It's a city?
>
>   Where is it?
>
>   Jujitsu? I'm going to learn Jujitsu?
>
>   If you're killed in the Matrix, you die here?
>
>   This, this isn't the Matrix?
>
>   What are they?
>
>   Someone?
>
>   Why?
>
>   What are you trying to tell me, that I can dodge bullets?
>
>   Squiddy?
>
>   EMP?
>
>   Where are we?
>
>   Sewers?
>
>   Is that...?
>   Do you always look at it encoded?
>
>   Of who?
>
>   See who?
>
>   I have these memories from my life. None of them happened. What does that mean?
>   Did you...?
>
>   And the Oracle can?
>
>   Did you go to her?
>
>   What did she tell you?
>
>   What?
>
>   So is this the same Oracle that made the prophecy?
>
>   The beginning?
>
>   And she knows what, everything?
>
>   She helped you?
>
>   What did she tell you?
>
>   What truth?
>
>   There is no spoon?
>
>   You're the Oracle?
>
>   What vase?
>
>   How did you know?
>
>   Who?
>
>   But what?
>
>   What?
>
>   What do you mean, without him?
>
>   What?
>
>   What is it?
>
>   Is Morpheus alive?
>
>   What are they doing to him?
>
>   How much time?
>
>   Well, what do they want?
>
>   Does it?
>
>   Why?
>
>   I believe I can bring him back. What are you doing?
>
>   Do what?
>
>   But what?
>
>   Can you fly that thing?**
>
> <sub><sup>Dialogue Transcript courtesy of http://thematrixtruth.remoteviewinglight.com/html/transcript-of-the-matrix-1.html</sup></sub>

Comment: What about implied questions? Quizzical looks, sorted by quizzicality?

Comment: @amaranth - Well, he spends the entire film looking slightly puzzled, but that's just how Keanu Reeves looks. He can't help it.

Comment: Seems that the red pill had some unforseen side effects

Comment: HAHAHAHA, I tried to count them, I counted 82, I think I missed some of them. I think is a good question because its odd the number of questions in a single film.

Comment: @Feuergeist - It's a bit of a toughie because some of his questions aren't completed; "*Is that...? Do you always look at it encoded?*" could be read as one question or two since he doesn't complete his thought.

Comment: If Neo, being a software developer and hacker, doesn't know what an EMP is... then he's the worst technologist in the Matrix.

Comment: @Ellesedil - You need to remember that he's in a bubble world. The only things he knows about are the things that the Architect has designed into the Matrix.

Comment: Sure. I'm simply assuming that nuclear weapons and science fiction exist in the Matrix considering humanity's penchant for conflict and the fact that there still appears to be interest in fantastical stories (the Oracle makes a reference to ghost stories in *Reloaded*).

Comment: @Ellesedil - Where did you learn about nukes and EMPs? Now imagine that whoever taught you (TV, school, books, etc) are all controlled by an intelligence that doesn't want you to know about them.

Comment: Why would the Architect want humanity to not know about them? They exist in the "real world", and the machines seem to have no problem with allowing humanity to retain them through 7 different versions of Zion. If they were a problem, the machines would have eradicated that knowledge after the first destruction of Zion. If the "real-life" machines tolerate EMPs, why would that be different in the Matrix where everything is completely fake?

Comment: @Ellesedil - My gut instinct is that if you were designing a fake world to house people, you'd withhold certain information. That would include info about how to make WMDs, if for no better reason than that it would disrupt things if someone was to set one off.

Comment: No one would set one off in the Matrix. Those unplugged wouldn't want to kill that many people, and the Agents would immediately stop anyone still plugged in who ended up having that desire or turn the WMDs into bricks (although a good question there is if the Matrix would even allow a plugged in individual to come up with the thought to actually detonate one considering what the actual plot revolves around).

Comment: @Ellesedil - There are a number of malcontents who're rejected by the Redpills. In "[Beyond](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaWOFmMiXZ4)" we see some kids playing in a glitch without necessarily having the mental strength required to actually exit the Matrix.